# R - sum a set number of rows from same column in a different data frame

Tags: r, sum, rows, calculated-columns

I have the following data frame:

```
    df <- data.frame( year = c(1985,1986,1987,1988,1989,1990,
                       1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,
                       2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009, 2010,
                       2011,2012, 2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020),

                     value = c(0,5,10,2,6,7,3,4,5,9,10,6,8,7,3,5,2,10,9,6,5,10,4,7,8,10,
                        4,6,8,9,2,3,7,6,2,1))
```

I want to create a second data frame (df2) that consists of 20 years intervals from the previous data frame, i.e.

```
df2 <- data.frame(year=c("1985-2005", "1986-2006","1987-2007", "1988-2008","1989-2009",
                         "1990-2010", "1991-2011","1992-2002", "1993-2003","1994-2004",
                         "1995-2005", "1996-2006","1997-2007", "1998-2008", "1999-2009",
                         "2000-2020"))
```

Now the `value` for `df2` should be the sum of `value` on `df` for 20 years intervals
(i.e., for year "1985-2005" in `df2`, the value is the sum of values from 1985 until 2005 in `df` - Excel snapshot attached with final values)

[image]

How can I perform this calculation? Also any possible automation to define the `year` interval in `df2` without having to type it?

Comment: I guess your Excel is not correctly calculated when, for instance, the period is 1992-2002: it is 69 and not 138!

Comment: It is probably a typo when putting the numbers in the "df$values" column - I did it manually - something I want to avoid by having the code! Thanks

Comment: Anyway, you now have a solution that works in R!

Comment: Actually, the typo is when typing the df2$year. It should be "1992-2012, "1993-2013", "1994-2014...up to 1999-2019 (it is now "1992-2002" and so on). I saw that when working with the real dataset. Any suggestions on how to create the df2$year automatically to avoid things like that?

Comment: Yes, just use the following: `df2$year <- paste(1985:2000, 1985:2000 + 20, sep="-")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame( year = c(1985,1986,1987,1988,1989,1990,
                       1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,
                       2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009, 2010,
                       2011,2012, 2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020),

                     value = c(0,5,10,2,6,7,3,4,5,9,10,6,8,7,3,5,2,10,9,6,5,10,4,7,8,10,
                        4,6,8,9,2,3,7,6,2,1))

df2 <- data.frame(year=c("1985-2005", "1986-2006","1987-2007", "1988-2008","1989-2009",
                         "1990-2010", "1991-2011","1992-2002", "1993-2003","1994-2004",
                         "1995-2005", "1996-2006","1997-2007", "1998-2008", "1999-2009",
                         "2000-2020"))

df2 %>% 
  separate(year, into = c("y1", "y2"), sep="-", convert = T, remove = F) %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(value = sum(df$value[df$year >= y1 & df$year <= y2])) %>% 
  select(-y1, -y2) %>% ungroup

#> # A tibble: 16 × 2
#>    year      value
#>    <chr>     <dbl>
#>  1 1985-2005   122
#>  2 1986-2006   132
#>  3 1987-2007   131
#>  4 1988-2008   128
#>  5 1989-2009   134
#>  6 1990-2010   138
#>  7 1991-2011   135
#>  8 1992-2002    69
#>  9 1993-2003    74
#> 10 1994-2004    75
#> 11 1995-2005    71
#> 12 1996-2006    71
#> 13 1997-2007    69
#> 14 1998-2008    68
#> 15 1999-2009    69
#> 16 2000-2020   124
```